# Implications of $R \cong M_n (D)$ for division ring $D$

Tags: modules, module-isomorphism

I am trying to show that if a ring $R \cong M_n (D)$ for some division ring $D$ (meaning isomorphic as rings) then $R=S \oplus … \oplus S$ ($n$ times).

Firstly I can see that $M_n(D) = C_1 + …+ C_n $ where $C_i $ is the ith column and there are just zeroes in all the other columns. I know that each column is isomorphic to $D^n $ which is simple as a left $M_n (D)$-module.

What I want to show that somehow using the isomorphism from $M_n(D)$ to $R$ we can use this to show the result but I’m a bit confused.

Comment: You forgot to mention what $S$ is.

Comment: A simple left $R$-module

Answer (score 0):

> $M_n(D) = C_1 + …+ C_n$

Yes, and in fact the sum is direct.

Perhaps what you are missing is that $M_n(D)$ only has one simple module (up to isomorphism)?  There are a couple ways to do this but the easiest is probably to see why there's only one Wedderburn component for this ring (because it is simple.)

---

> So if $:_()→$ is a ring isomorphism then $=(_1⊕…⊕_)=(_1)⊕…⊕(_)$. I know that each $_,_$ are isomorphic as modules but I need to show that $(_)$ and $(_)$ are isomorphic as modules so that then $≅⊕…⊕$ as modules where $=(_)$. I can’t seem to do this

The core question here is "If $\phi:R\to S$ is a ring isomorphism, and $f:M\to N$ is an isomorphism of $R$ modules, then in what sense are $M$ and $N$ isomorphic as $S$ modules?"

The only natural $S$ module structure available to $M$ and $N$ is that of transfer (via the ring isomorphism), where the action is defined by $\phi(r)\cdot x=rx$  (where $x$ comes from $M$, or $N$, whichever you have settled on.) You can check to see that all the $S$-module axioms are satisfied if you start with an $R$ module.  I use the dot here to help distinguish the $R$ action on $M$ from the $S$ action on $M$.

You can compatibly lift $f$ to be an $S$ module homomorphism with this action.  $f$ is already a group isomorphism of $M$ and $N$.  Does it respect the transferred action?

$\phi(r)\cdot f(m):=rf(m)=f(rm)=f(\phi(r)\cdot m)$

The first and last equalities are the definition of the transferred action, the middle one is $R$ linearity of $f$.  So $f$ is $S$ linear too.

Now you should be comfortable concluding that if $M_n(D)$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of $n$ mutually isomorphic simple left ideals, and $R$ is ring isomorphic to $M_n(D)$, then $R$ is also a direct sum of $n$ mutually isomorphic simple left ideals.

Comment: So if $\phi : M_n(D) \rightarrow R $ is a ring isomorphism then $R= \phi (C_1 \oplus … \oplus C_n )= \phi (C_1) \oplus … \oplus \phi (C_n) $. 

I know that each $C_i, C_j $ are isomorphic as modules but I need to show that $\phi (C_i )$ and $\phi (C_j ) $ are isomorphic as modules so that then $R \cong S \oplus … \oplus S $ as modules where $S= \phi (C_i )$. I can’t seem to do this